# One tool that WORKS for all archives and compressed files

Tags: zip, compression, unzip, 7zip

I have been using 7z, unrar , Peazip and Archive Manager and what not and I am having a hard time matching the compressed file/archive file with the appropriate tool for extracting.

The default ubuntu archive manager doesn't work for all type of file neither does 7z.

So what I am looking for is an utility that lets me extract any type of file. (for eg in windows 7zip does everything for me and I don't have to do anything. I am looking for something equivalent)

I am using ubuntu 20.x and I am looking for any CLI or GUI that does the thing.

Comment: Are you looking for a GUI that does everything, or “anything, so long as it works”?

Comment: You have not told us what version of Ubuntu you are using.  Most we can do is guess for what you are looking for.  In my experience though, the Engrampa Archive Manager that comes default in Xubuntu does pretty darn good at extracting from every compressed file I throw at it.  But it is not a GUI browser by itself.

Comment: There seems to be a 7zip for Linux on its download [site](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html).  Even if it isn't an official Ubuntu package, if you like 7zip so much, you should go with that, I think?